# Change the url parameters of incoming link

Tags: .htaccess

If I a user comes to the site

```
http://subdomain.example.com/faq/index.html
```

how to I pass it to the server as

```
http://subdomain.example.com?q=subdomain.com/faq/index.html?
```

The key is that I want the url to still look like the first URL, so I wouldn't want to redirect it.

I am also using php but I don't think I can accomplish this with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the second `?` is really just the question mark from the original question, you can capture the query string components like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([A-Z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?q=%1.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: According to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, the /faq/index.html are still in the URL.  How would I go about eliminate those directories from the new URL?  So it would become:
    http://subdomain.example.com?q=subdomain.com/faq/index.html?

Comment: @JacobKranz That's a cool site. Never looked around for a tester. I've updated my answer to include the preceding slash to the query. Also I had to remove the escape character I had in front of the period in the replacement query string.